# Populate <html:text> field from a <bean:write> tag

Tags: html, struts, struts-html

I want to populate a  field from a session bean.

I attempted this:

```
`<html:text
    property="docId"
    value="<bean:write name="queryResponseBean" property="queryResults" />" />`
```

but to no avail.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "value" attribute of the struts html:text tag will either except a string or a [RT Expr](https://www.google.com/search?q=RT%20Expr) (scriplet), therefore a nested expression like the one used above won't work. Instead, the value of the "queryResults" property will have to be set to a bean and then inserted into the "value" attribute using scripting language.

It will look something like this

```
<bean:define id="textVal" name="queryResponseBean" property="queryResults"/>
<html:text property="docId" value="<%=textVal%>"/>
```

Comment: and how to do with a value from a list? <html:text property='<%="list["+ idx +"].nve"%>' value="<%=String.valueOf(list[idx].nve) %>" />. gives me a error.

Answer (score 1):

A RT Expr is only allowed in the value attribute of the struts html:text tag, so avoid using nested expressions or JSP expression language.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value directly, don't use the `value=''` attribute:

```
html:text property="docId" property="queryResults" />
```

where `docId` must be a BeanClass and the property (`queryResults`) must be a field inside the BeanClass.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
<html:text 
    property="docId" 
    value="<bean:write name='${queryResponseBean}' property='queryResults' />" />
```

Comment: it doesn't like this either.

Instead of throwing a ServletException, it places "<bean:write... />" in the text field.